# Error: javascript key in invalid format integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
<input type="text" name="quantity">
```

I want this is a number(allow 0-9 and -), this is my code:

```
function update_quantity() {
   $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^-?\d]/g, ''));
}
$(document).on("change, keyup", "input[type=text])", update_quantity);
```

Ex:

```
123 -> valid
-123 -> valid
123- -> invalid
-1-12-123 -> invalid
-123-12 -> invalid
```

--> error can't auto replace -123-12 to -12312 or 123- to 123, how to fix it

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: There are syntax errors at `javascript`. What is expected result? Do you want to include `?` as accepted input?

Comment: Is `123---` valid input?

Comment: 123--- invalid! But -123 is valid

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `/^-?[0-9]+$/` also i don't really recommend doing this on `keyup`. should do it on `change` or `blur`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be what you are looking for:

https://jsfiddle.net/7vywp5nn/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name=quantity]').on('keyup',function() {
    var v = $(this).val();
    if (!v.match(/^-?[0-9]*$/))
      $(this).val(v.replace(/(?!^-)[^0-9]/g,''));
  });
});
```

Though I would personally do it on `change` or `blur` instead of stripping as user enters. Or better yet, return a visible error and prevent form submit, rather than auto-replace. I really hate form fields that do this sort of thing. Makes for bad UX IMO.

Answer (score 1):

> I want this is a number(allow 0-9 and -)
>
> 123--- invalid! But -123 is valid

Note, `RegExp` `/[^-?\d]/g` allows `?` character. If expected result is to allow `0-9` and `-` as first character, you can use `[^\d+]` without `?` character if value `.length` is `1` and value at index `0` is `-` return value at index `0` concatented to remainder of value using `.slice()` with parameter `1`, replacing characters that are not `-` or `\d+`, else replace `-` characters at end of input using `/(-)$/g`

`$(document).on("change, keyup", "input[type=text])", update_quantity);`

Comma at `"change, keyup"` and extra `)` at selector `"input[type=text])"` can be removed.

```js
function update_quantity() {
  $(this).val(function(_, val) {
      return val.length === 1 && val[0] === "-" 
             ? val[0] + val.slice(1).replace(/[^\d+]/g, "")
             : val.replace(/(-)$/g, "")
  });
}
$(document).on("change keyup", "input[type=text]", update_quantity);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text" name="quantity">
```